# Is a <style> tag inside a .css include file tolerated?

Tags: css

In a project, We have a `<style>` tag in the start of a CSS file (Because some editors don't show CSS highlighting otherwise):

```
<style>
body {
  ...
}
....
```

I know, this is [wrong inside a CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGCzN.jpg), because this would usually be the notation for inline CSS inside HTML but it seems also to be tolerated (at least by Firefox 49) if the `<style>` tag is set **inside the CSS include  file** right at the start.

I Try to find out, If I have to correct this in our Project or leave it as it is, which I would prefer if it is largely tolerated (at least by Firefox since version 26)

Comment: that's interesting. Best practices is that you don't need to include the `<style>` tags when you're using a `.css` stylesheet.

Comment: what is issue  ??

Comment: It's invalid CSS. Browser tolerance doesn't make it valid. I haven't heard of any CSS hacks out there which rely on such a tolerance, just scrape it, a copy-paste mistake which went unnoticed.

Comment: No, it is there on purpose, due to syntax highlighting problems in our team. so I don't want to remove it if it is tolerated by **ALL** browsers (which seems so)

Comment: I cannot recall any instance of a greater than or less than operator ever used in an external CSS stylesheet nor the need to use an html tag. I know very little of the post-processed types like LESS, SCSS, SASS, etc. Perhaps that's what you have there? Just saw `(Because some editors don't show CSS highlighting otherwise):` added and that makes total sense.

Comment: This is not valid no. <style> is a tag and doesn't belong in a css file. Probably an amateur that copy pasted something as stated above.

Comment: It's invalid: http://imgur.com/a/GHjbp

Comment: If your editor can't display CSS highlighting on a .css file without this, it's time for a new editor! What editors are you refering to?

Comment: I don't know and don't care, it is a large team

Comment: If you need the CSS highlighting in your text editor, you could put the `<style>` tags between CSS comments `/* ... */`

Comment: What editor are you using? I can't imagine any editor not supporting CSS. Can't you install SUblime or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question as asked, but ....

It's invalid CSS. Kill it. Kill it with fire.

Just because it is tolerated now, there is no guarantee that it will be tollerated in the future. Who know's in a future spec there may be a special meaning to a tag in a css file, unlikely but who know's.

It's bad enough in the world of web development that we introduce hacks to handle browser peculiarities, hell the whole jquery library was built around this concept, and then there is the clearfix hack, browser resets etc. It seems to be a bad idea to introduce a hack to support an editor.

If I was leading this team I'd be saying that you can use whatever editor you like (actually I'd say choose from this approved set) as long as it is able to work with valid code.

Answer (score -1):

though did not get your question clearly but you don't need to add "style" tag in your css file if it is a .css file and if you want it in any php or html file you should start with "style" and have to end this in the head section this is basic!

Comment: Sure, I know how to use CSS normally.  I am an experienced developer. I edited my question so maybe it gets clearer what I want to know